# How to find version number of VisualSVN Server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Is there a way to see the version number of the VisualSVN Server software on the server website (ex: `https://MyVisualSvnServer/svn`)?

If not, where can I find the version number on the server itself?

Comment: Do you want to know version of Apache Subversion that VisualSVN Server is built against **or** you want to know version of VisualSVN Server itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my instance, when I open VisualSVN Server on the server, there is a link at the bottom of the main window that contains the version number. When you click on it, it provides more info:

[image: VisualSVN Server Version]

I don't believe you can get the version via client software - it has to be retrieved from the server.

Is this what you were after?

Answer (score 14):

Navigate to `https://MyVisualSvnServer/svn` and view the HTML source of the page.
You'll find the version number in the version attribute of the root `<svn>` tag.

Example:
    `<svn version="1.7.8 (r1419691)...`

Comment: Worked for me.  Then, with that Apache Subversion number, look for the version of VisualSVN based on that from THIS page: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/

Answer (score 2):

VisualSVN Server does not display version number in web interface for security reasons. Version number display on dashboard in VisualSVN Server Manager. You may click on it to see detailed version information.

Comment: I don't buy that's "the reason".  After all, I'm pretty sure an SVN server MUST reveal its "SVN version number" so the client can use the right version of the interface protocol.  OK, I agree, that is not same as the VisualSVN version number... but with the tip from @elusive-platypus, you can get pretty close given the SVN version number.

Comment: @DanH Subversion reveals protocol capabilities on OPTIONS request, but it doesn't reveal full version number. It's common practice to hide server software version information for clients.